# How to import dependencies in groovy inline scripts in maven

Tags: maven, groovy, pact

I wanted to add an inline groovy script in maven pom.xml.

Currently I am working with Contract Testing with Pact where I wanted to added a inline groovy script in  to replace the auth token dynamically for provider verification

So either experts in Pact jvm or Groovy could help me here.

Code in my pom.xml

```
<serviceProvider>
     <name>MyAPI</name>
     <requestFilter>
         **<Import statements and make a call to secrets manager>**
         request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer <Token>')
     </requestFilter>
     <pactBrokerUrl>https://pact.myapie.com</pactBrokerUrl>
     <protocol>https</protocol>
     <port>443</port>
     <host>api.com</host>
</serviceProvider>
```

Whatever I have written inside  tag is a groovy script

Here I wanted to call Secrets Manager and get the creds

But I am not able to import any statements here.

Your help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So given the maven-pact-jvm [docs](https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/provider/maven#modifying-the-http-client-used) you can definitely include an import in your pom script.  This real issue is how to get the libs you are dependent upon into the classpath of pact-jvm? I'd either say you would add your dependencies to your test classpath in maven, or you might be able to use a `@Grab` annotation in your groovy script.